# Nested List with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html-lists

I just need to use PHP and MySQL to create a nested or multi-level list. How can I make this show all customers and then all phone numbers related to each given customer.

For example:

John

555 555-5555

666 666-6666

Kristen

777 777-7777

Amy

888 888-8888

999 999-9999

222 222-2222

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,"
SELECT 
fname,
phone
FROM 
customer,
phone,
customer_phone
WHERE
customer.id=customer_phone.customer_id
AND
phone.id=customer_phone.phone_id
");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['fname'];
echo "<br />";
echo $row['phone'];
echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: We'll need more information on your table structure.

Comment: customer has id and fname. phone has id and phone. customer_phone is a junction table with customer_id and phone_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the order by and how I only print the name the first time it comes up. Also, learn to join properly using the "on" clause.

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,"
SELECT fname, phone
FROM customer
join customer_phone on customer.id=customer_phone.customer_id
join phone on customer_phone.phone_id=phone.id
order by fname
");
$oldname = null;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($oldname != $row['fname'])
    {
        echo $row['fname']."<br>";
        $oldname = $row['fname'];
    }
    echo $row['phone']."<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Kainaw. That works and gives me a good example to study. Baby steps, man.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a customer class, this way i can store more information than just phone or name

```
class Customer {
   public $phone = array();
   public $name = '';
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$customerList[$row['fname']] = new Customer;
$customerList[$row['fname']]->name = $row['fname'];
array_push($customerList[$row['fname']]->phone, $row['phone'])
}
```

but u can also just do a simple array with key is customer name and value is array of customer phone if there's nothing else u wanna store